# SQL Server Fulltext PDF German

Tags: sql-server, pdf, full-text-search

Using SQL Server 2012 I installed the Acrobat PDF Filter 11.0.1.36.
The filter is active and working, but only in english, but my column to index is actually set to be german.

As I fill the column with german content, the (german) words will not show up.
When I fill the column with english content, the (english) words will show up.

When I use a .docx or a .txt the german language is recognized. Any suggestions on how to switch the language for the pdf filter?

Comment: can you please explain along with examples

Comment: I create a .docx with the german words "Zimmer", "Schlüssel" in it. I saved that as .docx and as .pdf (out of word), then I copied those 2 words to a .txt file and filled 3 rows in my table with each file.
Wenn I search (CONTAINS) for any of the words, only the .docx and the .txt are found.
Then I created a word file using "room" and "keys", I saved a pdf and uploaded that english file into my table.
Now when I search for "room" it will find the english pdf, but the german version of the pdf is not indexed. the document count on "Zimmer" or "Schlüssel" is 2 (.docx and .txt) and not 3